# Replace current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to replace the current activity with a new one. That is, I want to start a new activity and remove the current activity from the task stack.

Based on the documentation, it seems the best way would be to start the activity using [Activity.startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) as per usual, and then call [Activity.finish](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) immediately to close the current activity.

Is this a valid usage of these APIs or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. It is fine to use api this way.

Comment: Does this work with startActivityForResult? If so, where does the result get posted?

Comment: For people wondering about @nmr's question, what I've been doing is starting the new activity for result, and then call finish() in the onActivityResult as needed.

Comment: Can you explain the difference of not using `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME)`, as is shown in @Jeremie D's answer?

Answer (score 47):

The proper way to achieve this is using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

The code assumes you are in an activity, otherwise if you are using fragments use *getActivity()*

This way, the activity is started, you properly set your hierarchy for your back button, and you also destroy the appropriate activity.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is and what would happen if you do not set these flags with `setFlags`?

Answer (score 7):

try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the intent flags

Answer (score 6):

You can add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in your activity, then override onNewIntent method to update date

Reference
[PlayerActivity in ExoPlayer Demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/PlayerActivity.java)

Comment: this is a really useful thing to do if you have a logical/functional "Home" page and you use a lot of navigation (like a navigation drawer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK when you start the activity. I also defined the launchMode for my activity in the manifest as singleTask, but that was because I wanted that behavior for the new activity. I think you can get what you want with regard to clearing the previous activity regardless of what you use for launchMode with your new activity, as long as you pass startActivity the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.