# Moving between activities: killing two previous activities

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I'm very new on Android, and I see that if Iaunch a new Intent from an activity, this activity goes to paused state.

If I want that user can't goes back to this previous activity, what must I do? May I kill this previous activity with finish?

**UPDATE**
An example:

A, B C and D are activities. 
A is the first activity.

A launches B, and B launches C, and C launches D.

I want to close or kill activity B and C when D is launched.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace current activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116158/replace-current-activity)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate question. I want to maintain in stack the first activity.

Comment: Do it as you said. when launching C call finsih() in B

Answer (score 5):

You can use your intent to startActivity like normal and follow the startActivity with

`finish();`

If you do this on your hypothetical activity B, you can hit the hardware back button in C and it'll take you directly to A.

Comment: This answer isn't quite what he asked for, though it may still be what he wanted. Suppose activity B was for some reason FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and activity C tried to launch another B. It would pop off activity C, even though ideomatically B shouldn't be on the stack anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rework your design. What if you have A call startActivityForResult(B, 0), and when B would have launched C, instead setResult and finish. Back in A, onActivityResult gets called, with the result you set. You can use that result as a message for A to now start the activity C.

Comment: Maybe, I can use startActivityForResult with the same requestCode for B, C and D. And when D launches activity E, it can kills all of them with finishActivity(requestCode);

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (This and other flags)

And also you must invoke

```
finish();
```