# How to Obtain a Reference to the Most Recently-Visited Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a simple application that entails multiple activities.  It is necessary for my application to resume one of two activities based on a certain system preference.  Because of this, I have implemented a `Dispatcher` class that is linked to `action.MAIN`, that then starts the correct `Activity` by examining the system preferences within its `onResume()` callback.

### The Problem

Since I am doing this in `onResume()`, when the back button is pressed on any of the resulting activities, the `Dispatcher` is resumed, and as a result it again tries to start the same `Activity` again.  This prevents the user from ever leaving the application unless they press the home button.

### Some Code

Here is some code excerpts from my classes to help clarify my situation:

*Dispatcher.onResume(void) : void*

```
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    if(!handled){

        Intent activity_switcher;

        //If a game is active...
        if(manager.isGameActive()){

            //Start the the Game Manager with the appropriate game.
            activity_switcher = new Intent(this, GameManager.class);
        }
        //If a game is not active... 
        else{

            //Start the Game Menu
            activity_switcher = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        }

        //Start the appropriate activity
        startActivity(activity_switcher);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
    else{

        //Finish the application
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Some of the variables are as follows:

- `manager` is the variable representing my class that interfaces with the system preferences.
- `handled` is the variable that determines if the event has been handled yet (see "Attempted Solution #1" below)

### Attempted Solution #1

I have considered implementing a boolean class variable, `handled`, that is tested before the activities are started.  If the value is found to be `true`, then the `Dispatcher` simple makes a call to `finish()`, however if the value is `false`, then the appropriate activity is started and `handled` is set to `true` so that when the application returns to this `Activity`, it will simply finish.

*This will not work, because...*

If the user pressed the home button on one of the resulting activities, then when they resume the application, they will be placed on the dispatcher activity, and the application will immediately finish because it thinks that it was handled (the variable is still true).

### Attempted Solution #2

I tried to find some way to only run to the `Dispatcher` once per application life cycle.  This makes sense because the user would never want to return to the `Dispatcher` as it is an `Activity` that should only be ran once at launch time.  So, I included a counter that would be incremented each time onResume() was called, and reduced to 0 each time finish() was called.

*This will not work, because...*

Again, if the user presses the home button, then when the application is re-launched, the `Dispatcher` will **think** that it has already been run once (because there was no call to `finish()`), and will immediately finish again.

### Attempted Solution #3

I figured that if I could somehow determine which activity was previously active, then I could dynamically react to the case where the user pressed the back button, and then *and only then* inform the `Dispatcher` that it should finish, then there would be no immediate finishes in the case when the user presses the home button.

This was accomplished by using a static function `returningFromMenu()` that, when called from the menu `Activity`, raised a flag in the `Dispatcher` class that informed the it to finish.

### Attempted Solution #4 (Current Implementation)

Simply moving all of this activity switching code into onCreate().  This would enforce the "one time" nature of the `Dispatcher`.

*This might work, because...*

This will handle the case where the user returns to the activity (using onResume()), and, since there will be no flags, there is no issue when returning to the application after pressing the home button.

---

### My Question

Is there any way to determine which `Activity` was last finished, other than having to use a static method or member?  I know that this is a very bad practice and would like to avoid it  if possible.

### Updates

*Last Updated: 12 Feb 2013 3:45PM EST*

Approach #4 seems to be working for my purposes, however I still think that the question here could be of great use to developers, and will refrain from answering my question until I have given enough time for a more holistic solution to be posted.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing something, but why can't you just call `finish()` immediately after `startActivity(activity_switcher);`? Of course, your `onCreate()` method is fine, also. An alternative might be to get rid of `Dispatcher`, and do your dispatching in `onCreate()` of the Game Menu activity. This way it will just jump into an active game if detected, but the back button will go back to the menu(which seems like expected, "typical" behaviour to me).

Comment: I was unaware that after you started an Activity you could do anything else.  To clarify, I thought that when you started an Activity, the system *immediately* executed the code and stopped progressing through the original Activity code.  Would calling finish() in this manner remove the Activity from the back stack?  If so, then this would be a very insightful solution to my problem.  Further, the reason I have the Dispatcher is to handle any cases wherein the game is stopped abruptly.  In these cases, you would never want to return to the menu, but rather go straight back to the game.

Comment: I haven't tried it this way, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116158/replace-current-activity) seems to indicate it will work. I see what you're saying about the dispatcher, but it does seem a slightly unintuitive flow to me.

Comment: 99% sure just adding `finish()` after starting the activity will work. And no, activities can truly run in the background so code in the previous activity could potentially still be executing (the UI can't be updated though).

Comment: Ahh, brilliant!  I will be using this in my applications from now on.  Thank you very much.  If I may ask, though, what part does not seem intuitive?  I'd like to make the game flow as naturally as possible.

Comment: FYI: the problem you are having is that your dispatcher activity still lies in the activity stack. the call to finish() will remove it from there, so taping on the back button will not open it again. another way to achieve the same is to add the noHistory attribute to the activity definition in the manifest file. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Solution

As is stated in "Updates" above, this problem was solved by simply moving the code into `onCreate()` so that the switch was made only once.  Equivalently, I could have simply made a call to `finish()` immediately after starting the activity in order to remove the calling activity from the back stack.

Thank you all for your efforts in the comment section!